# How to fill Combo box inside DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have two two classes like this (I'm giving short version):

```
public class Assistant: RegisteredUser, INotifyPropertyChanged
        private int institution;
        private int professor;

        public Assistant(int id, bool active, string name, string lastName, string email, string username, string password,  ScheduleBehavior scheduleBehavior, int professor, int institution)
            : base(id, active, name, lastName, email, username, password,  scheduleBehavior)
        {
            this.professor = professor;
            this.institution = institution;
        }

    public class Professor : RegisteredUser, INotifyPropertyChanged
           {

            private List<Assistant> assistants;
            private int institution;

            public Professor(int id, bool active, string name, string lastName, string email, string username, string password, ScheduleBehavior scheduleBehavior, List<Assistant> assistants, int institution)
                : base(id, active, name, lastName, email, username, password, scheduleBehavior)
            {
                this.assistants = assistants;
                this.institution = institution;
            }
```

Somewhere during inital load of MainWindow, I will save objects in two static hash maps like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, Assistant> assistants = load("assistants");
public static Dictionary<int, Professor> professors = load("professors");
```

Keys are Id fields of objects themselves.

As instance variables in my window I have following:

```
private ICollectionView assistantsView;
private ICollectionView professorsView;
private ObservableCollection<Assistant > assistants;
private ObservableCollection<Professor> professors;
```

Assistant tabItem, called tabAssistans, which contains DataGrid (dgAssistants) is set up like this:

```
dgAssistants.DataContext = assistants;
assistantsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(assistants);
dgAssistants.ItemsSource = assistantsView;
dgAssistants.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true
cbColumnProfessors.ItemsSource = professors;  //drop down list of available proffesors
```

Xaml for dgAssistants:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgAssistants" Margin="-2,-8,-2,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="false">

  <DataGrid.Columns >

          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="*"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="*"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="*"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="*"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="*"/>
           <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbColumnProfessors" Header="Professor" Width="*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Professor, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Professor" >
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="yourCBSelectionChanged" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>


 private void yourCBSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            Assistant rowAssistant = (Assistant)dgAssistants.CurrentItem;
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            Professor selectedProfessor = professors[cmb.SelectedIndex];
            cmb.SelectedItem = selectedProfessor;
            dgAssistants.UpdateLayout();


            FileTextIO.Edit(rowAssistant, Assistant.PATH);

        }
```

I did manage with all this to populate data grid and to populate combo boxes (in each row) with Professors. Only that. I need a way to "bind" somehow that combo box and Assistant object of that row.

Problem is how to display names of professors in combo box and once I first time open window to set selectedItem of combo box to be the value of Name of Assistant's Professor. And if the value of Professor is -1 then combo box should be displaying nothing (like it is empty).

[image: when the window is first time opened]

Comment: Does the `Assistant` class have some kind of "SelectedProfessor" property? It should (or must) for you to be able to store the currently selected professor somewhere.

Comment: @mm8 Ohh, yes, it has (Professor). All the properties are there, along with setters having "On Property Changed"...

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedValueBinding` should bind to a property of the `Assistant` class that stores the currently selected professor and the `DisplayMemberPath` property should be set to the *name* of a property of the `Professor` class. You also need to set the `SelectedValuePath` property to the name of property of the `Professor` class where you get the value to be selected from:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbColumnProfessors" Header="Professor" Width="*"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Professor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedValuePath="Id"  />
```

Comment: Thank you mm8, for replaying. Yes, your code works, the combobox is being populated with professors and their names. Now, I don't know if you noticed, field professor in the Assistant class is an int. How to set for each row (i.e each Assistant) in dgAssistants, in the combobox to be set at name of that Assistant's Professor. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this understandably :)

Comment: @MiljanPuletic: Set the `SelectedValuePath` property to the name of the corresponding `int` property in the `Professor` class. See my edit.

Comment: I was trying something with IValueConverter, but it wasn't going well..

Comment: Hi sir, I tried this one more time as you said, but unfortunately, I'm not getting desired results. Every combobox has been set on the first value from list of professors and once I make any selection from combobox and hit Enter, value in combobox returns on the first value from list. I made edit so you can see.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the setter of the `Professor`, does it get hit? What's the value it's being set to?